# Unexpected JS/jQuery Loop Behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following loop. The goal is to automatically show text boxes when a user chooses certain options in a dropdown list.

For some reason, in the following code, the loop assigns the "sponsor" field to the associated array for "blurb". I cannot figure out why. How can I make this work?

Thanks so much.

```
function add_fields_on_change ()
{
    var map = {
        "sponsor"   :   Array("New Sponsor", "new_sponsor"),
        "blurb"     :   Array("New Blurb Suggestion", "new_blurb")
    };
    for (field in map)
    {
        alert($('.bound[name='+field+']').val()); //alerts as expected
        $('.bound[name='+field+']').change(function() {
            alert(map[field][0]); //alerts "New Blurb Suggestion" for both "sponsor" and "blurb" fields
            if ($(this).val() == map[field][0])
            {
                 $('.hidden[name='+map[field][1]+']').show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You really ought to use `["New Sponsor", "new_sponsor"]` for creating an array. Using `Array` can lead to surprising quirks - see what `Array(2)` returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that the event handler you're creating (which is a closure) has an *enduring reference* to the `field` variable, not a *copy* of it as of when the function was created. So all of the event handlers that get created will see the same value of `field` (the last value assigned to it).

Because you're already using jQuery, the easiest solution is probably to use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
function add_fields_on_change ()
{
    var map = {
        "sponsor"   :   Array("New Sponsor", "new_sponsor"),
        "blurb"     :   Array("New Blurb Suggestion", "new_blurb")
    };
    $.each(map, function(field, value) {
        alert($('.bound[name='+field+']').val()); //alerts as expected
        $('.bound[name='+field+']').change(function() {
            alert(map[field][0]); //alerts "New Blurb Suggestion" for both "sponsor" and "blurb" fields
            if ($(this).val() == map[field][0])
            {
                 $('.hidden[name='+map[field][2]+']').show();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

That works because the event handlers close over the call to the iterator function you're passing into `each`, and so they each get their own `field` argument, which never changes.

If you wanted to do it without using `$.each` for whatever reason, you'd do something like this:

```
function add_fields_on_change ()
{
    var map = {
        "sponsor"   :   Array("New Sponsor", "new_sponsor"),
        "blurb"     :   Array("New Blurb Suggestion", "new_blurb")
    };
    var field;
    for (field in map)
    {
        alert($('.bound[name='+field+']').val()); //alerts as expected
        $('.bound[name='+field+']').change(createHandler(field));
    }

    function createHandler(f) {
        return function() {
            alert(map[f][0]); //alerts "New Blurb Suggestion" for both "sponsor" and "blurb" fields
            if ($(this).val() == map[f][0])
            {
                 $('.hidden[name='+map[f][3]+']').show();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

It's the same principle, the event handler closes over the call to `createHandler` and uses the `f` argument, which is unique to each call, and which we're never assigning a new value to.

Note that I declared the `field` variable. That declaration was missing from your original code, which means you were falling prey to the [Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

More reading:

- *[Closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)*

Comment: This makes sense. Is there a better way, functionally, to re-write this? Obviously I could hardcode each of these associations, but I was trying to make this scalable, as I have a feeling the powers that be will want other options on this form to do something similar.

Comment: Ahhh..Interesting. I hadn't thought of using each like that. That fixed it! Thank you! Will accept as soon as that is permitted.

Comment: Thanks for the other method and further reading. All super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a custom attribute to your fields, avoiding the closures problem:

```
function add_fields_on_change ()
{
    var map = {
        "sponsor"   :   Array("New Sponsor", "new_sponsor"),
        "blurb"     :   Array("New Blurb Suggestion", "new_blurb")
    };
    for (field in map)
    {
        $('.bound[name='+field+']').attr('data-name', map[field][0]);
        $('.bound[name='+field+']').attr('data-hidden', map[field][1]);
        $('.bound[name='+field+']').change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == this.attr('data-name'))
            {
                 $('.hidden[name='+this.attr('data-hidden')+']').show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```